# Guava Charmatcher static initialization slow

Tags: java, guava

UPDATE: It looks like my 13.0.1 is calling code from this diffed CharMatcher.

http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/source/diff?spec=svn69ad96b719d7cd3d872a948d7454f17b816a21c2&r=464b0cfab7c3b6713c35e6f3ae7426542668c77b&format=side&path=/guava/src/com/google/common/base/CharMatcher.java

I seem to be having an issue with Guava's Charmatcher.  I am currently writing some JUnit tests and I am noticing the first test takes a bit of time (15+ seconds), but the future tests are all approximately the same (.3 seconds), with a majority of the tests running through the same code.

My analysis of the code has pinpointed that the Charmatcher in Guava's library seems to be the culprit. It looks like there is a bit of static initialization code in CharMatcher that might be the true reason it is taking so long.  Is there any way I can disable or optimize this behavior? Is there something I am missing from the wiki pages or help files?

Guava version 13.0.1, System: Linux 64, Eclipse 3.6.1

EDIT:
I built a test app with the following code:

```
import com.google.common.base.CharMatcher;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Using system instead of stopwatch to isolate library.
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        CharMatcher.is(' ');
        long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("took " + String.valueOf(endTime-startTime) + " ms");

        startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        CharMatcher.is('d');
        endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("2nd took " + String.valueOf(endTime-startTime) + " ms");
    }
}
```

This resulted in the following output:

```
took 15945 ms
2nd took 0 ms
```

I ran this in eclipse minus the JUnit framework and just google's guava library.  Also I packaged an executable char and received similar results.  I'll come back with a second edit after I run a profiler through it.

Thanks for any help.

Edit 2:
Results from profiling:

```
Main.main(String[])                                                                  22,556 ms
com.google.common.base.CharMatcher.<clinit>()                                     22.556 ms                                    
    com.google.common.base.CharMatcher.precomputed()                                 22,550 ms                      
        com.google.common.base.Platform.precomputeCharMatcher(CharMatcher)           22,550 ms
            com.google.common.base.CharMatcher.precomputedInternal()                  22,550 ms
                com.google.common.base.CharMatcher.slowGetChars()                    13,638 ms
                com.google.common.base.CharMatcher.setBits(CharMatcher$LookupTable)  8,911 ms
```

Comment: There's nothing you're missing -- but can you actually determine that `CharMatcher`, by itself, takes 15 seconds to load up?  Sure, `CharMatcher` does some static initialization, but 15 seconds seems much longer than I'd expect.

Comment: @LouisWasserman - I profiled it, and it was indeed, in my case, CharMatcher at the root of the issue, but it is as much Hotspot's fault as Guava's (see my answer below).

BTW, I still thing it's nice not to do a ton of work at static init time, even when it is JIT'd properly, so I filed [this bug](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/issues/detail?id=1192), to maybe improve that.

Comment: Yes, I would prefer the static variables be loaded lazily although I realize it will be more work, especially if you want to guarantee thread-safety (although it's probably not a big deal that two threads get two different immutable objects that are the same thing)

Comment: Guaranteeing thread safety in this case isn't difficult.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Update:** This is [fixed](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/issues/detail?id=1192) in Guava 14.

You are running into some kind of JIT bug present in u21, and likely earlier versions, but not in at least some later JDK versions.  Here's the -XX:+PrintCompilation output for your test program in u21:

```
  1       java.util.Arrays::binarySearch0 (72 bytes)
  2       com.google.common.base.CharMatcher$Or::matches (28 bytes)
  3       com.google.common.base.CharMatcher$12::matches (22 bytes)
  2   made not entrant  com.google.common.base.CharMatcher$Or::matches (28 bytes)
  4       com.google.common.base.CharMatcher$11::matches (17 bytes)
  5       java.util.Arrays::binarySearch (9 bytes)
  6       com.google.common.base.CharMatcher$Or::matches (28 bytes)
  1%      com.google.common.base.CharMatcher::slowGetChars @ 9 (52 bytes)
  6   made not entrant  com.google.common.base.CharMatcher$Or::matches (28 bytes)
  7       com.google.common.base.CharMatcher$Or::matches (28 bytes)
  7   made not entrant  com.google.common.base.CharMatcher$Or::matches (28 bytes)
  1%  made not entrant  com.google.common.base.CharMatcher::slowGetChars @ -2 (52 bytes)
  2%      com.google.common.base.CharMatcher::slowGetChars @ 9 (52 bytes)
  8       com.google.common.base.CharMatcher$Or::matches (28 bytes)
  8   made not entrant  com.google.common.base.CharMatcher$Or::matches (28 bytes)
  2%  made not entrant  com.google.common.base.CharMatcher::slowGetChars @ -2 (52 bytes)
  3%      com.google.common.base.CharMatcher::slowGetChars @ 9 (52 bytes)
  9       com.google.common.base.CharMatcher$Or::matches (28 bytes)
  9   made not entrant  com.google.common.base.CharMatcher$Or::matches (28 bytes)
  3%  made not entrant  com.google.common.base.CharMatcher::slowGetChars @ -2 (52 bytes)
  4%      com.google.common.base.CharMatcher::slowGetChars @ 9 (52 bytes)
 10       com.google.common.base.CharMatcher$Or::matches (28 bytes)
 10   made not entrant  com.google.common.base.CharMatcher$Or::matches (28 bytes)
  4%  made not entrant  com.google.common.base.CharMatcher::slowGetChars @ -2 (52 bytes)
 11       com.google.common.base.CharMatcher$Or::matches (28 bytes)
  5%      com.google.common.base.CharMatcher::slowGetChars @ 9 (52 bytes)
 11   made not entrant  com.google.common.base.CharMatcher$Or::matches (28 bytes)
 12       com.google.common.base.CharMatcher$Or::matches (28 bytes)
  5%  made not entrant  com.google.common.base.CharMatcher::slowGetChars @ -2 (52 bytes)
 12   made not entrant  com.google.common.base.CharMatcher$Or::matches (28 bytes)
  6%      com.google.common.base.CharMatcher::slowGetChars @ 9 (52 bytes)
 13       com.google.common.base.CharMatcher$Or::matches (28 bytes)
 13   made not entrant  com.google.common.base.CharMatcher$Or::matches (28 bytes)
  6%  made not entrant  com.google.common.base.CharMatcher::slowGetChars @ -2 (52 bytes)
  7%      com.google.common.base.CharMatcher::slowGetChars @ 9 (52 bytes)
 14       com.google.common.base.CharMatcher$Or::matches (28 bytes)
 15       com.google.common.base.CharMatcher::slowGetChars (52 bytes)
 14   made not entrant  com.google.common.base.CharMatcher$Or::matches (28 bytes)
  7%  made not entrant  com.google.common.base.CharMatcher::slowGetChars @ -2 (52 bytes)
 16       com.google.common.base.CharMatcher$Or::matches (28 bytes)
 16   made not entrant  com.google.common.base.CharMatcher$Or::matches (28 bytes)
 17       com.google.common.base.CharMatcher$Or::matches (28 bytes)
 17   made not entrant  com.google.common.base.CharMatcher$Or::matches (28 bytes)
  8%      com.google.common.base.CharMatcher::slowGetChars @ 9 (52 bytes)
 18       com.google.common.base.CharMatcher$Or::matches (28 bytes)
 18   made not entrant  com.google.common.base.CharMatcher$Or::matches (28 bytes)
 19       com.google.common.base.CharMatcher$Or::matches (28 bytes)
 19   made not entrant  com.google.common.base.CharMatcher$Or::matches (28 bytes)
 20       com.google.common.base.CharMatcher$Or::matches (28 bytes)
  8%  made not entrant  com.google.common.base.CharMatcher::slowGetChars @ -2 (52 bytes)
 20   made not entrant  com.google.common.base.CharMatcher$Or::matches (28 bytes)
 21       com.google.common.base.CharMatcher$Or::matches (28 bytes)
 21   made not entrant  com.google.common.base.CharMatcher$Or::matches (28 bytes)
 22       com.google.common.base.CharMatcher$Or::matches (28 bytes)
  9%      com.google.common.base.CharMatcher::slowGetChars @ 9 (52 bytes)
 22   made not entrant  com.google.common.base.CharMatcher$Or::matches (28 bytes)
 23       com.google.common.base.CharMatcher$Or::matches (28 bytes)
 23   made not entrant  com.google.common.base.CharMatcher$Or::matches (28 bytes)
 24       com.google.common.base.CharMatcher$Or::matches (28 bytes)
 24   made not entrant  com.google.common.base.CharMatcher$Or::matches (28 bytes)
  9%  made not entrant  com.google.common.base.CharMatcher::slowGetChars @ -2 (52 bytes)
 25       com.google.common.base.CharMatcher$Or::matches (28 bytes)
 25   made not entrant  com.google.common.base.CharMatcher$Or::matches (28 bytes)
 26       com.google.common.base.CharMatcher$Or::matches (28 bytes)
 26   made not entrant  com.google.common.base.CharMatcher$Or::matches (28 bytes)
 10%      com.google.common.base.CharMatcher::slowGetChars @ 9 (52 bytes)
 27       com.google.common.base.CharMatcher$Or::matches (28 bytes)
 27   made not entrant  com.google.common.base.CharMatcher$Or::matches (28 bytes)
 28       com.google.common.base.CharMatcher$Or::matches (28 bytes)
 28   made not entrant  com.google.common.base.CharMatcher$Or::matches (28 bytes)
 10%  made not entrant  com.google.common.base.CharMatcher::slowGetChars @ -2 (52 bytes)
 29       com.google.common.base.CharMatcher$Or::matches (28 bytes)
 29   made not entrant  com.google.common.base.CharMatcher$Or::matches (28 bytes)
 30       com.google.common.base.CharMatcher$Or::matches (28 bytes)
 30   made not entrant  com.google.common.base.CharMatcher$Or::matches (28 bytes)
 11%      com.google.common.base.CharMatcher::slowGetChars @ 9 (52 bytes)
 31       com.google.common.base.CharMatcher$Or::matches (28 bytes)
 31   made not entrant  com.google.common.base.CharMatcher$Or::matches (28 bytes)
 32       com.google.common.base.CharMatcher$Or::matches (28 bytes)
 32   made not entrant  com.google.common.base.CharMatcher$Or::matches (28 bytes)
 11%  made not entrant  com.google.common.base.CharMatcher::slowGetChars @ -2 (52 bytes)
 33       com.google.common.base.CharMatcher$Or::matches (28 bytes)
 33   made not entrant  com.google.common.base.CharMatcher$Or::matches (28 bytes)
 34       com.google.common.base.CharMatcher$Or::matches (28 bytes)
 34   made not entrant  com.google.common.base.CharMatcher$Or::matches (28 bytes)
 35       com.google.common.base.CharMatcher$Or::matches (28 bytes)
 12%      com.google.common.base.CharMatcher::slowGetChars @ 9 (52 bytes)
 35   made not entrant  com.google.common.base.CharMatcher$Or::matches (28 bytes)
 36       com.google.common.base.CharMatcher$Or::matches (28 bytes)
 36   made not entrant  com.google.common.base.CharMatcher$Or::matches (28 bytes)
 37       com.google.common.base.CharMatcher$Or::matches (28 bytes)
 37   made not entrant  com.google.common.base.CharMatcher$Or::matches (28 bytes)
 12%  made not entrant  com.google.common.base.CharMatcher::slowGetChars @ -2 (52 bytes)
 38       com.google.common.base.CharMatcher$Or::matches (28 bytes)
 38   made not entrant  com.google.common.base.CharMatcher$Or::matches (28 bytes)
 39       com.google.common.base.CharMatcher$Or::matches (28 bytes)
 39   made not entrant  com.google.common.base.CharMatcher$Or::matches (28 bytes)
 13%      com.google.common.base.CharMatcher::slowGetChars @ 9 (52 bytes)
 40       com.google.common.base.CharMatcher$Or::matches (28 bytes)
 40   made not entrant  com.google.common.base.CharMatcher$Or::matches (28 bytes)
 41       com.google.common.base.CharMatcher$Or::matches (28 bytes)
 41   made not entrant  com.google.common.base.CharMatcher$Or::matches (28 bytes)
 13%  made not entrant  com.google.common.base.CharMatcher::slowGetChars @ -2 (52 bytes)
 42       com.google.common.base.CharMatcher$Or::matches (28 bytes)
 42   made not entrant  com.google.common.base.CharMatcher$Or::matches (28 bytes)
 43       com.google.common.base.CharMatcher$Or::matches (28 bytes)
 43   made not entrant  com.google.common.base.CharMatcher$Or::matches (28 bytes)
 44       com.google.common.base.CharMatcher$Or::matches (28 bytes)
 14%      com.google.common.base.CharMatcher::slowGetChars @ 9 (52 bytes)
 44   made not entrant  com.google.common.base.CharMatcher$Or::matches (28 bytes)
 45       com.google.common.base.CharMatcher$Or::matches (28 bytes)
 45   made not entrant  com.google.common.base.CharMatcher$Or::matches (28 bytes)
 46       com.google.common.base.CharMatcher$Or::matches (28 bytes)
 46   made not entrant  com.google.common.base.CharMatcher$Or::matches (28 bytes)
 14%  made not entrant  com.google.common.base.CharMatcher::slowGetChars @ -2 (52 bytes)
 47       com.google.common.base.CharMatcher$Or::matches (28 bytes)
 47   made not entrant  com.google.common.base.CharMatcher$Or::matches (28 bytes)
 48       com.google.common.base.CharMatcher$Or::matches (28 bytes)
 48   made not entrant  com.google.common.base.CharMatcher$Or::matches (28 bytes)
 15%      com.google.common.base.CharMatcher::slowGetChars @ 9 (52 bytes)
 49       com.google.common.base.CharMatcher$Or::matches (28 bytes)
 49   made not entrant  com.google.common.base.CharMatcher$Or::matches (28 bytes)
 50       com.google.common.base.CharMatcher$Or::matches (28 bytes)
 50   made not entrant  com.google.common.base.CharMatcher$Or::matches (28 bytes)
 15%  made not entrant  com.google.common.base.CharMatcher::slowGetChars @ -2 (52 bytes)
 51       com.google.common.base.CharMatcher$Or::matches (28 bytes)
 51   made not entrant  com.google.common.base.CharMatcher$Or::matches (28 bytes)
 52       com.google.common.base.CharMatcher$Or::matches (28 bytes)
 52   made not entrant  com.google.common.base.CharMatcher$Or::matches (28 bytes)
 16%      com.google.common.base.CharMatcher::slowGetChars @ 9 (52 bytes)
 53       com.google.common.base.CharMatcher$Or::matches (28 bytes)
 53   made not entrant  com.google.common.base.CharMatcher$Or::matches (28 bytes)
 54       com.google.common.base.CharMatcher$Or::matches (28 bytes)
 54   made not entrant  com.google.common.base.CharMatcher$Or::matches (28 bytes)
 16%  made not entrant  com.google.common.base.CharMatcher::slowGetChars @ -2 (52 bytes)
 55       com.google.common.base.CharMatcher$Or::matches (28 bytes)
 55   made not entrant  com.google.common.base.CharMatcher$Or::matches (28 bytes)
 56       com.google.common.base.CharMatcher$Or::matches (28 bytes)
 56   made not entrant  com.google.common.base.CharMatcher$Or::matches (28 bytes)
 57       com.google.common.base.CharMatcher$Or::matches (28 bytes)
 17%      com.google.common.base.CharMatcher::slowGetChars @ 9 (52 bytes)
 57   made not entrant  com.google.common.base.CharMatcher$Or::matches (28 bytes)
 58       com.google.common.base.CharMatcher$Or::matches (28 bytes)
 58   made not entrant  com.google.common.base.CharMatcher$Or::matches (28 bytes)
 59       com.google.common.base.CharMatcher$Or::matches (28 bytes)
 59   made not entrant  com.google.common.base.CharMatcher$Or::matches (28 bytes)
 17%  made not entrant  com.google.common.base.CharMatcher::slowGetChars @ -2 (52 bytes)
 60       com.google.common.base.CharMatcher$Or::matches (28 bytes)
 60   made not entrant  com.google.common.base.CharMatcher$Or::matches (28 bytes)
 61       com.google.common.base.CharMatcher$Or::matches (28 bytes)
 61   made not entrant  com.google.common.base.CharMatcher$Or::matches (28 bytes)
 18%      com.google.common.base.CharMatcher::slowGetChars @ 9 (52 bytes)
 62       com.google.common.base.CharMatcher$Or::matches (28 bytes)
 62   made not entrant  com.google.common.base.CharMatcher$Or::matches (28 bytes)
 63       com.google.common.base.CharMatcher$Or::matches (28 bytes)
 63   made not entrant  com.google.common.base.CharMatcher$Or::matches (28 bytes)
 18%  made not entrant  com.google.common.base.CharMatcher::slowGetChars @ -2 (52 bytes)
 64       com.google.common.base.CharMatcher$Or::matches (28 bytes)
 64   made not entrant  com.google.common.base.CharMatcher$Or::matches (28 bytes)
 65       com.google.common.base.CharMatcher$Or::matches (28 bytes)
 65   made not entrant  com.google.common.base.CharMatcher$Or::matches (28 bytes)
 19%      com.google.common.base.CharMatcher::slowGetChars @ 9 (52 bytes)
 66       com.google.common.base.CharMatcher$Or::matches (28 bytes)

<I omitted ~500 very similar lines here>

143%  made not entrant  com.google.common.base.CharMatcher::setBits @ -2 (30 bytes)
144%      com.google.common.base.CharMatcher::setBits @ 2 (30 bytes)
144%  made not entrant  com.google.common.base.CharMatcher::setBits @ -2 (30 bytes)
145%      com.google.common.base.CharMatcher::setBits @ 2 (30 bytes)
145%  made not entrant  com.google.common.base.CharMatcher::setBits @ -2 (30 bytes)
took 7599 ms
2nd took 0 ms
```

Here's the same output for u34:

```
 64   1       java.util.Arrays::binarySearch0 (72 bytes)
 68   2       com.google.common.base.CharMatcher$Or::matches (28 bytes)
 68   3       com.google.common.base.CharMatcher$12::matches (22 bytes)
 70   4       com.google.common.base.CharMatcher$11::matches (17 bytes)
 71   5       java.util.Arrays::binarySearch (9 bytes)
 71   1%      com.google.common.base.CharMatcher::slowGetChars @ 9 (52 bytes)
 76   2      made not entrant  com.google.common.base.CharMatcher$Or::matches (28 bytes)
 76   6       com.google.common.base.CharMatcher$Or::matches (28 bytes)
 88   1%     made not entrant  com.google.common.base.CharMatcher::slowGetChars @ -2 (52 bytes)
 88   6      made not entrant  com.google.common.base.CharMatcher$Or::matches (28 bytes)
 88   7       com.google.common.base.CharMatcher::slowGetChars (52 bytes)
 89   8       com.google.common.base.CharMatcher$Or::matches (28 bytes)
 91   9       com.google.common.base.CharMatcher$8::matches (14 bytes)
 91   2%      com.google.common.base.CharMatcher::slowGetChars @ 9 (52 bytes)
 98  10       java.lang.String::indexOf (166 bytes)
 98  11       java.lang.String::indexOf (151 bytes)
102   3%      com.google.common.base.CharMatcher::setBits @ 2 (30 bytes)
113  12       com.google.common.base.CharMatcher::setBits (30 bytes)
113  13       com.google.common.base.CharMatcher$LookupTable::set (15 bytes)
```

As you can see, it is a hell of a lot more sane in u34.  It looks like what is happening in u21 is that some combination of [OSR](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9105505/149138) (affecting `slowGetChars` method as it has a large loop), and recursive megamorphic calls (affecting `CharMatcher$Or` and other subclasses of `CharMatcher` - which are called at the end of the recursive `CharMatcher$Or` chain) produce a perfect storm of JIT de-optimization and subsequent recompilation, which is resolved in u34.

Still, I think the Guava guys are being a bit abusive by creating a 65k element LUT during static init, even if you never use the matchers in question, which takes still about ~50ms when JIT is working properly. I filed [a bug](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/issues/detail?id=1192) against guava, let's see if the maintainers agree :). *Update:* the bug was fixed within a couple of days of me filing this, the fix will be in Guava 14. That's what I call quick turnaround!

**Original post follows:**

I have the exact same behavior and ran into this post looking for a solution.

Looking at the code, it seems that they are making a 65k element (each element takes one bit) lookup table and checking if every character matches, which in this requires many nested function calls due to the *fluent* style being used to define the matchers:

```
  public static final CharMatcher INVISIBLE = inRange('\u0000', '\u0020')
      .or(inRange('\u007f', '\u00a0'))
      .or(is('\u00ad'))
      .or(inRange('\u0600', '\u0604'))
      .or(anyOf("\u06dd\u070f\u1680\u180e"))
      .or(inRange('\u2000', '\u200f'))
      .or(inRange('\u2028', '\u202f'))
      .or(inRange('\u205f', '\u2064'))
      .or(inRange('\u206a', '\u206f'))
      .or(is('\u3000'))
      .or(inRange('\ud800', '\uf8ff'))
      .or(anyOf("\ufeff\ufff9\ufffa\ufffb"))
      .withToString("CharMatcher.INVISIBLE")
      .precomputed();
```

That's the code that is triggering the long static init, which on my fast box takes ~7 seconds.  Here's the output of your app on my box:

```
took 6814 ms
2nd took 0 ms
```

I'm filing a guava bug.

Comment: Thats a great in depth analysis.  I'm still wrapping my head around your answer as some terms are new to me, such as "OSR" and "megamorphic".  I'm guessing I would have a better understanding if I had worked on Java compilers and optimizing said compilers.  Good work.  I'm going to leave this question open for another day but it looks like your in depth analysis determined the root cause.  I'm going to request a later version of Java.

Comment: OSR means "on stack replacement".  It basically means that the JIT compiler needs to compile a method that is currently running, and usually happens when a method contains a large loop - part way through the loop, (after 10,000 iterations, by default with the server compiler) the compiler decides that it is worthwhile to compile the method, but unfortunately it's not a straightforward replacement because the method is already running!  So the compiled method has some limitations that normal replacement doesn't have.

Comment: Here's a good [reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9105505/differences-between-just-in-time-compilation-and-on-stack-replacement).

Comment: Megamorphic basically means that some method call (at some specific site) is in practice satisfied by multiple different overriding (or implementing in the case of interfaces) classes.

In theory, this applies to *all* method calls, since they are all _virtual_ in java.  In practice, however, most call sites hit only a single method, so the JIT may optimistically optimize for that case, removing the virtual call mechanism and making a static call, or even inlining the call.

Comment: When it does this, it will add something called an 'inline cache', which is a quick runtime check prior to non-virtual or inlined call, to check that the target object is actually of the expected type.  If this check fails, the method needs to be deoptimized.  

If a method has two implementors in practice, it may be called _bimorphic_, while three or more is often called _megamorphic_ (strictly speaking this should include the 2 target case).  The JDK can't the megamorphic case as well, since it needs to use virtual dispatch).

Comment: It's relevant here mostly because a function being megamorphic causes deoptimization, (the "made not entrant lines") and could be a cause of the repeated JIT.  CharMatcher has many implementations, including the CharMatcher$Or, which appears in the stack, but Or ultimately ends in a non-Or implementation, which is exactly the kind of scenario where the JIT will "guess wrong".

Answer (score 2):

As a quick help, try to switch to the newest version from the [source repo](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/source/checkout). There are changes there, e.g. the method `slowGetChars` is [gone](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/issues/detail?id=1049#c2). It used to be a bit slow, but nowhere near what's happening to you.

For everybody else it runs some hundred times faster and without being able to reproduce it it's hard to help.

Comment: I looked at the diff, and it looks like this might be the issue.

Comment: Also I can't report back if the new source code fixes the issue as I work on a closed network that can take weeks to approve patches or downloads from the internet :(

Comment: It used to be a bit slow, but surely not that slow. I and thousands of others didn't notice any problem (it was just that I was curious how it works). There's something very unique with you configuration.

Comment: I am working with an older machine, but you're right, there shouldn't be that much of a difference.

Answer (score 1):

Just tested with :

```
@Test
public void testCharMatcherSlow() throws Exception {
    System.out.println(CharMatcher.JAVA_DIGIT.matches('1'));
}
```

and it took 0.06sec to execute. Also looked at the CharMatcher code, and nothing could explain the slow behavior you encounter. You should replace the CharMatcher by a mock to see that it is not the issue and maybe use a profiler to find out the cause.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran the exact benchmark you provided, and got

> took 74 ms
>
> 2nd took 0 ms

...Perhaps the problem is on Eclipse's end?  Are you running in debug mode?

Comment: The problem is I built an executable JAR file and ran that standalone too. I'm running java build 1.6.0_13-b03, I'm wondering if that is an issue?

Comment: nevermind about the java version, I ran it with 1.6.0_22 and had the same issue.  It looks like it's taking the most time in some recursive call: `com.google.common.base.CharMatcher$Or.matches(char)`