# Guava-Splitter on Android takes 1.7 seconds to initialize?

Tags: java, android, performance, guava, lag

I'm investigating a lag, occurring after the first touch-input of my android-application. I used TraceView and tracked down the ~2 second lag to the initialization of Guava's `Splitter`.

[image]

- Why does this take so long?
- Am I reading TraceView's output correctly?
- What can I do about this?

This is the line invoking `Splitter`:

```
String desc = /* loaded from assets */
List<String> descList = Lists.newArrayList(Splitter.on("\n").split(desc));
```

Comment: ...and what's the code for Splitter you use?

Comment: It would certainly appear that you are reading Traceview correctly. As to the why and what to do issues, that needs a Guava expert.

Comment: A helper that loads a text-file from assets into the String. The String is about 50 characters long, and the call to my helper takes less than 1ms according to TraceView. Also, after the first Splitter.on() subsequent calls to it are fast.

Comment: Why not use `Splitter.on('\n')` instead of `Splitter.on("\n")`?

Comment: I noticed that and changed my code. No change in performance.

Comment: @LouisWasserman, love you man, but you have to admit that tip was kinda supremely useless :-) sorry.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think this might be related to [Guava Charmatcher static initialization slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13143401/guava-charmatcher-static-initialization-slow) and http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/issues/detail?id=1192 , since you need to construct a CharMatcher when constructing a Splitter. As you can see in TraceView, a lot of time is spent in `CharMatcher.<clinit>` (clinit = class initialization).

What version of Guava are you using?

Comment: Fabian, can you tell us what you see when you switch to 14.0-rc2? The linked issue is believed fixed there.

Comment: Solved with 14.0-rc1 and -rc2. Thanks.