# Why use "inner Class" instead of using "new" directly?

Tags: java, guava

When I learn guava,I found some code like this in com.google.common.hash.Hashing class:

```
public static HashFunction crc32c() {
    return Crc32cHolder.CRC_32_C;
}

private static final class Crc32cHolder {
    static final HashFunction CRC_32_C = new Crc32cHashFunction();
}
```

I want to know, why do not write like below, Is this merely the author's habit? or for other purpose?

```
public static HashFunction crc32c() {
    return new Crc32cHashFunction()
}
```

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initialization-on-demand_holder_idiom

Comment: There is no inner class here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your alternative suggestion

```
public static HashFunction crc32c() {
    return new Crc32cHashFunction()
}
```

would create a new `Crc32cHashFunction` instance each time `crc32c()` is called. If there is no specific need for a new instance to be returned by each call, it is more efficient to return the same instance in each call.

Using the static final variable

```
static final HashFunction CRC_32_C = new Crc32cHashFunction();
```

is one way to achieve a single instance.

As to why the `HashFunction` instance is a member of the nested class `Crc32cHolder` (as opposed to being a member of the outer class), the motivation is probably lazy evaluation - only at the first time the `crc32c()` method is called, the `Crc32cHolder` class would be initialized and the `Crc32cHashFunction` instance would be created. Thus, if that method is never called, the `Crc32cHashFunction` would never be created (assuming there is no other access to the `Crc32cHolder` class).

Comment: And the lazy loading works because `crc32c` (and presumably the whole class it is contained in) only talks about the abstract `HashFunction` in their signature, so that the concrete `Crc32cHashFunction` class (and its instance holder class) does not need to be resolved unless anyone actually calls that method.

Comment: Do you know why the singleton is not just a static field on `Crc32cHashFunction`, though? What does the extra holder indirection bring to the table?

Comment: @Thilo I don't know the use case here (and I don't have time to dig into that code), but perhaps they don't want that static field to be initialized when `Crc32cHashFunction` class is first accessed. I don't know what other code may be using `Crc32cHashFunction` - perhaps such other code doesn't use that single instance (i.e. there are use cases in which `Crc32cHashFunction` class is initialized but you don't want to initialize that static variable).

Comment: @Thilo See how [loading from classes may be slow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13143401/581205) (there was a bug causing it to be extremely slow, but even without it, it takes some non-negligible time) and [how it can be postponed](https://github.com/google/guava/blob/master/guava/src/com/google/common/base/CharMatcher.java#L255) (for compatibility reasons, the legacy constants causing the loading are still there).