# Why does this code using streams run so much faster in Java 9 than Java 8?

Tags: java, performance, java-8, java-stream, java-9

I discovered this while solving [Problem 205](https://projecteuler.net/problem=205) of [Project Euler](https://projecteuler.net/). The problem is as follows:

> Peter has nine four-sided (pyramidal) dice, each with faces numbered 1, 2, 3, 4.
>   Colin has six six-sided (cubic) dice, each with faces numbered 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6.
>
> Peter and Colin roll their dice and compare totals: the highest total wins. The result is a draw if the totals are equal.
>
> What is the probability that Pyramidal Pete beats Cubic Colin? Give your answer rounded to seven decimal places in the form 0.abcdefg

I wrote a naive solution using Guava:

```
import com.google.common.collect.Sets;
import com.google.common.collect.ImmutableSet;

import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.math.RoundingMode;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Problem205 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        List<Integer> peter = Sets.cartesianProduct(Collections.nCopies(9, ImmutableSet.of(1, 2, 3, 4)))
                .stream()
                .map(l -> l
                        .stream()
                        .mapToInt(Integer::intValue)
                        .sum())
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        List<Integer> colin = Sets.cartesianProduct(Collections.nCopies(6, ImmutableSet.of(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)))
                .stream()
                .map(l -> l
                        .stream()
                        .mapToInt(Integer::intValue)
                        .sum())
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        long startTime2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        // IMPORTANT BIT HERE! v
        long solutions = peter
                .stream()
                .mapToLong(p -> colin
                        .stream()
                        .filter(c -> p > c)
                        .count())
                .sum();

        // IMPORTANT BIT HERE! ^
        System.out.println("Counting solutions took " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime2) + "ms");

        System.out.println("Solution: " + BigDecimal
                .valueOf(solutions)
                .divide(BigDecimal
                                .valueOf((long) Math.pow(4, 9) * (long) Math.pow(6, 6)),
                        7,
                        RoundingMode.HALF_UP));
        System.out.println("Found in: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime) + "ms");
    }
}
```

The code I have highlighted, which uses a simple `filter()`, `count()` and `sum()`, seems to run much faster in Java 9 than Java 8. Specifically, Java 8 counts the solutions in 37465ms on my machine. Java 9 does it in about 16000ms, which is the same whether I run the file compiled with Java 8 or one compiled with Java 9.

If I replace the streams code with what would seem to be the exact pre-streams equivalent:

```
long solutions = 0;
for (Integer p : peter) {
    long count = 0;
    for (Integer c : colin) {
        if (p > c) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    solutions += count;
}
```

It counts the solutions in about 35000ms, with no measurable difference between Java 8 and Java 9.

What am I missing here? Why is the streams code so much faster in Java 9, and why isn't the `for` loop?

---

I am running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS 64-bit. My Java 8 version:

```
java version "1.8.0_131"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_131-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.131-b11, mixed mode)
```

My Java 9 version:

```
java version "9"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 9+181)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 9+181, mixed mode)
```

Comment: If you're not using a micro-benchmarking test harness, such as JMH, you're doing it wrong and your conclusions about the execution speed may be wrong.

Comment: @scottb I did consider that, but I don't see how some code consistently running twice as fast in Java 9 than in Java 8 could be solely caused by lazy benchmarking. There has to be some good reason for it.

Comment: Java 9 has a bunch of [JVM enhancements](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/whatsnew/toc.htm#JSNEW-GUID-0564E449-0601-4EEC-B130-73ABD83074AC), such as improved caching and dynamic linking.

Comment: *"... but I don't see how some code consistently running twice as fast in Java 9 than in Java 8 could be solely caused by lazy benchmarking."* -  Just because you can't see how doesn't mean that it can't happen.

Comment: Yep.  Sounds like a benchmarking issue, not an actual performance difference.

Comment: Do you have something _against_ better performance (perceived or otherwise)?

Comment: The argument about poor benchmarking doesn't apply here, since the code isn't a microbenchmark - it is a complete standalone application that solves the certain task. So, the real question here is why JIT behaves so strange in this particular example.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

#### 1. Why the stream works faster on JDK 9

`Stream.count()` implementation is [rather dumb](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/jdk/file/601a2304ff4a/src/share/classes/java/util/stream/LongPipeline.java#l426) in JDK 8: it just iterates through the whole stream adding `1L` for each element.

This was [fixed](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8067969) in JDK 9. Even though the bug report says about SIZED streams, new code improves non-sized streams, too.

If you replace `.count()` with Java 8-style implementation `.mapToLong(e -> 1L).sum()`, it will be slow again even on JDK 9.

#### 2. Why naive loop works slow

When you put all your code in `main` method, it cannot be JIT-compiled efficiently. This method is executed only once, it starts running in interpreter and later, when JVM detects a hot loop, it switches from interpreted mode to compiled on-the-go. This is called on-stack replacement (OSR).

OSR compilations are often not as optimized as regular compiled methods. I've explained this in detail earlier, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33858960/3448419) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42590152/3448419) answer.

JIT will produce better code if you put the inner loop in a separate method:

```
    long solutions = 0;
    for (Integer p : peter) {
        solutions += countLargerThan(colin, p);
    }

    ...

    private static int countLargerThan(List<Integer> colin, int p) {
        int count = 0;
        for (Integer c : colin) {
            if (p > c) {
                count++;
            }
        }
        return count;
    }
```

In this case `countLargerThan` method will be compiled normally, and the performance will be better than with streams both on JDK 8 and on JDK 9.

Comment: Which improvements were made for `count()` on non `SIZED` streams?

Comment: @Holger New [`TerminalOp`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk9/jdk9/jdk/file/65464a307408/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/stream/ReduceOps.java#l236) with a specialized sink. Now there is no intermediate mapping operation in the pipeline, and there is no extra indirection in reduce.