# Why does moving an iteration-invariant vector out of a loop induce unnecessary GC activity?

Tags: java, performance, garbage-collection, vectorization, java-19

I am testing manual vectorization in Java with the `jdk.incubator.vector` API (JDK 19), and have come across some unexpected behavior w.r.t. Garbage Collection, exemplified here with a toy `memset` implementation.

In the following code, the functions `memsetLoop1` and `memsetLoop2` are functionally identical, with the only difference being whether the `LongVector.broadcast` takes place in or outside of the inner loop. Because the broadcasted value is the same for every iteration of the inner loop, this is a correct "optimization."

However, my measurements (in the `main` function) indicate `memsetLoop2` takes about 50% longer to complete, on average.

```java
// Run with `--source=19 --add-opens java.base/jdk.internal.misc=ALL-UNNAMED --enable-preview --enable-native-access=ALL-UNNAMED --add-modules jdk.incubator.vector`
package main;

import java.lang.foreign.*;
import java.nio.ByteOrder;
import jdk.incubator.vector.*;

public class VectorGCBugDemo {
    // I am aware that the below line of code is generally a Very Bad Idea.
    // It has no bearing on the issue at hand, AFAICT.
    final static MemorySegment ADDRESS_SPACE = MemorySegment.ofAddress(MemoryAddress.NULL, Long.MAX_VALUE, MemorySession.global());
    final static ByteOrder NATIVE_BYTE_ORDER = ByteOrder.nativeOrder();
    final static long SPECIES256_VECTOR_SIZE = LongVector.SPECIES_256.vectorByteSize();

    // Something that fits in L1 cache, for maximum speed.
    static final long ALLOCATION_BYTES = 512L * SPECIES256_VECTOR_SIZE;
    // Big number to make unexpected GC behavior visible.
    static final long ITERATIONS = 50_000_000L;

    static void memsetLoop1(final long address, final long bytes, final long iterations) {
        final long start = address;
        final long end = address + bytes;
        for (long outer = 0; outer < iterations; outer++) {

            // vvvvvvvv INNER LOOP 1 vvvvvvvv
            for (long i = start; i < end; i += SPECIES256_VECTOR_SIZE) {
                LongVector.broadcast(LongVector.SPECIES_256, outer).intoMemorySegment(ADDRESS_SPACE, i, NATIVE_BYTE_ORDER);
            }

        }
    }

    static void memsetLoop2(final long address, final long bytes, final long iterations) {
        final long start = address;
        final long end = address + bytes;
        for (long outer = 0; outer < iterations; outer++) {

            // vvvvvvvv INNER LOOP 2 vvvvvvvv
            final LongVector broadcastedValue = LongVector.broadcast(LongVector.SPECIES_256, outer);
            for (long i = start; i < end; i += SPECIES256_VECTOR_SIZE) {
                broadcastedValue.intoMemorySegment(ADDRESS_SPACE, i, NATIVE_BYTE_ORDER);
            }

        }
    }
    
    public static void main(String... args) {
        // Allocate vector-aligned memory.
        final MemorySegment allocation = MemorySegment.allocateNative(ALLOCATION_BYTES, SPECIES256_VECTOR_SIZE, MemorySession.global());
        final long allocationAddress = allocation.address().toRawLongValue();

        System.out.print("Running memsetLoop1... ");
        final long t1 = System.nanoTime();
        memsetLoop1(allocationAddress, ALLOCATION_BYTES, ITERATIONS);
        final long t2 = System.nanoTime();
        System.out.printf("memset loop took %.2fns on average.\n", (double)(t2 - t1) / ITERATIONS);
        
        System.out.print("Running memsetLoop2... ");
        final long t3 = System.nanoTime();
        memsetLoop2(allocationAddress, ALLOCATION_BYTES, ITERATIONS);
        final long t4 = System.nanoTime();
        System.out.printf("memset loop took %.2fns on average.\n", (double)(t4 - t3) / ITERATIONS);
    }
}
```

Looking at the x86 code generated by the JIT compiler for each function (via `-XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -XX:+PrintAssembly` and the `hsdis` library) doesn't seem to show any differences between them; the compiler is more than smart enough to move the `vpbroadcastq` instruction out of the loop in `memsetLoop1`, and they both end up looking pretty much the same to my (somewhat inexpert) eye.

However, running it with `-verbose:gc` with default heap sizes reveals significant GC activity during the execution of `memsetLoop2`, while `memsetLoop1` does not have any:

```
[0.002s][info][gc] Using Serial
WARNING: Using incubator modules: jdk.incubator.vector
Running memsetLoop1... memset loop took 271.30ns on average.
Running memsetLoop2... [15.305s][info][gc] GC(0) Pause Young (Allocation Failure) 268M->1M(968M) 2.190ms
[17.037s][info][gc] GC(1) Pause Young (Allocation Failure) 268M->1M(968M) 1.836ms
[18.808s][info][gc] GC(2) Pause Young (Allocation Failure) 268M->1M(968M) 0.862ms
[20.607s][info][gc] GC(3) Pause Young (Allocation Failure) 268M->1M(968M) 0.856ms
[22.369s][info][gc] GC(4) Pause Young (Allocation Failure) 268M->1M(968M) 0.955ms
[24.128s][info][gc] GC(5) Pause Young (Allocation Failure) 268M->1M(968M) 0.750ms
[25.887s][info][gc] GC(6) Pause Young (Allocation Failure) 268M->1M(968M) 0.928ms
[27.646s][info][gc] GC(7) Pause Young (Allocation Failure) 268M->1M(968M) 0.755ms
[29.405s][info][gc] GC(8) Pause Young (Allocation Failure) 268M->1M(968M) 0.750ms
[31.213s][info][gc] GC(9) Pause Young (Allocation Failure) 268M->1M(968M) 0.858ms
[32.972s][info][gc] GC(10) Pause Young (Allocation Failure) 268M->1M(968M) 0.752ms
memset loop took 405.50ns on average.
```

Using higher outer loop counts just results in even more GC activity for `memsetLoop2`.

Lowering the heap sizes to their minimum values shows that `memsetLoop1` does initially have some light GC activity, but the allocations generated by direct interpretation of the loop code seem to get optimized out by the JIT, while in `memsetLoop2` this is not the case for whatever reason.

I am quite puzzled by these facts, as I would expect functions to be optimized essentially identically once the iteration-invariant code is lifted out of the loop. If anyone has any clues as to why this behavior might be occurring, an explanation would be very much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Every time people write a Java benchmark manually, they end up measuring an [OSR compilation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9105505/differences-between-just-in-time-compilation-and-on-stack-replacement). This is misleading, see [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54410675/3448419), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33858960/3448419), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42590152/3448419), [4](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46637432/3448419). Just use [JMH](https://github.com/openjdk/jmh). You apparently looked at the assembly of a regular JIT compilation, but that was not what JVM actually ran.

Comment: I will work on testing with JMH tomorrow. However, looking at the JIT output I analyzed, I was comparing the _second_ compilation of each of the memset loops, which means they are not compiled in OSR mode, according to your second link (they do not contain a % in the "C2-compiled method" header).

Comment: That's what I said. You looked at the output of a normal compilation, but measured OSR one.

Comment: You emphasized that you compared the *second* compilation. But when do you think the *second* compilation is executed, if the method is called only *once*?

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. I misunderstood the OSR stub description. If I run each of them twice before timing them, they both have identical and much lower runtimes, with the allocations correctly elided and all. Thank you!