# Does Hotspot JVM perform Escape Analysis during On Stack Replacement compilation?

Tags: java, jvm, jvm-hotspot, escape-analysis

Consider the following code:

```
void methodWithOSR() {
    Foo foo = new Foo(); // this object doesn't escape
    for (int i = 0; i < 1_000_000; i++) {
        // some code that uses `foo`
    }
}
```

Is Hotspot JVM able to scalarize `foo` on the stack, when C2 OSR compilation kicks in? I suppose that it might be problematic, because a live object already exists in heap, so it might be not possible to "move" object from heap to stack and registers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not quite clear what "scalaraize" means in this situation, but let me paraphrase the question.

> Does HotSpot JVM run Escape Analysis during OSR compilation?

Yes. Most compiler features/optimizations are valid for OSR compilation just like for a regular compilation.

> Does HotSpot benefit from Escape Analysis with respect to "scalarization" (whatever it mean) of `Foo` instance here?

The main goal of scalar replacement is allocation elimination, which is not applicable to Foo instance since the object is already allocated in heap.

> Will HotSpot move live object from heap to stack?

No. There is no point in doing so. Stack is just another memory area.

> Can HotSpot optimize access to `Foo` fields here?

Yes. It may cache fields in registers, for example, like in [this case](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33858960/3448419). However, the modifications will be still written back to the heap.