# Why is Kotlin's mapOf(a to b, c to d) considered not suitable for performance-critical code?

Tags: kotlin

Kotlin's [official "collections" page](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/collections.html) contains the following remark:

> Map creation in NOT performance-critical code can be accomplished with
>   simple idiom: mapOf(a to b, c to d).

Questions:

a/ What is the reason behind this remark (the best explanation I could come up with is that the "a to b" expressions create an extra, transient, Pair object, but I am not sure).

b/ What is the suggested best practice for initializing a map in a way that *is* suitable for performance-critical code?

Comment: Performance critical  !=  performant

Comment: @diginoise - rephrased

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There are two things that happen under the hood that might affect performance:

- The [`mapOf(...)`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/map-of.html) function expects a `vararg` of pairs, and, during a call, an array is created for the arguments and then passed to the function. This operation involves allocating an array and then filling it with the items.
- As you correctly noted, the [`a to b`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/to.html) [infix function](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/functions.html) creates a pair (equivalent to `Pair(a, b)`), which is another object allocation.

Allocating many objects affects performance when done many times in *tight loops* (including additional load on garbage collector, when dealing with short-living objects).

Additionally, using an array for the `vararg` may affect *locality of reference* (instead of passing the arguments through the stack, they are placed into a separate memory region located somewhere else in the heap).

While JVMs are usually good at local optimizations and can sometimes even [eliminate allocations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38521299/will-the-jit-optimize-new-objects), these optimizations are not guaranteed to happen.

A more performant way to create a map and fill it with items is:

```
val map: Map<Foo, Bar> = HashMap().apply { 
    put(a, b)
    put(c, d)
}
```

<sup>Using [`apply { ... }`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/apply.html) introduces no overhead since it is an [inline function](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/inline-functions.html).</sup> <sup>An explicit type annotation `Map<Foo, Bar>` shows the intention not to mutate the map after it is created.</sup>

Comment: You can also use the assignment approach. Not much difference in this case, but could code in the apply with `this[a] = b`. I prefer the myMap[a] = b, but obviously it's preference.