# Does the JVM remove unnecessary class instantiation?

Tags: java, optimization, jvm

Let's say I have a class

```
Box(double xi, double yi, double zi, double xf, double yf, double zf)
```

and I have a method

```
Box#collides(Box other){
   if(other.xf < xi || other.xi > xf) return false;
   if(other.yf < yi || other.yi > yf) return false;  
   return other.zf >= zi && other.zi <= zf;
}
```

I then get two boxes. I compare the first

```
Box(a,b,c,d,e,f)
```

with `.collides()` to the other box,

```
Box(A,B,C,D,E,F)
```

Will the Box objects still be created? Or will the JVM be smart and use something similar to

```
static collides(double xi, double yi, double zi, double xf, double yf, double zf, double xi, double oyi, double ozi, double oxf, double oyf, double ozf){
   if(oxf < xi || oxi > xf) return false;
   if(oyf < yi || oyi > yf) return false;  
   return ozf >= zi && ozi <= zf;
}
```

---

This might seem like a micro-optimization, but in my case, potentially millions of `Box`es are being instantiated.

Comment: You’re asking if there are two box objects will they disappear and a new method be created?

Comment: I am asking if the JVM will not have to create the box objects and instead use something similar to the static method I provided.

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38578777/3448419)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may or may not happen. The HotSpot JVM an do this, but only when everything gets inlined in a single method (there are no intra-procedural optimizations other than those converted to inter-procedural by inlining).

It must see the while allocation, the test and the running out-of-scope in a single procedure (after inlining). This may well happen, but there's no guarantee. However, a few million boxes means about a few times 60 megabytes, which is a lot, but allocating a few MB per second is pretty common.

If you want to be sure, provide a method like `Box#collides(double xi, double yi, double zi, double xf, double yf, double zf)`.